# How do I iterate through and add to each nested list within a greater list based on values used in API call?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, html-lists, nested-lists

I have been pounding my head to figure out a solution to what I think may be a relatively simple issue - however, I'm new to python and it takes ages to make the smallest bit of progress (part of what makes it fun, eh).

Here is the goal of my project:

1. Scrape all the members on the Board of Directors from this page on wsj: https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/AAPL/company-people
2. Replace "AAPL" in the url request with a variable, then iterate through to pull the members on the board from multiple companies (it is a two column table)
3. Put into a dataframe to make it novice-friendly so I can split cols, add cols, upload to a CRM, etc.

---

So far, I've been able to scrape the two-column table off the page using a list of stock tickers, iterating and appending as a nested list into a larger list.

I convert to df and I get two columns - Name/Title, Current Board Membership

**My issue:** I need to create a third column (stock ticker) that was used to find the table in my nested lists to begin with.

Here is my code for reference (leaving out the header variable to save space - lmk if I should post):

```
data = []
tickers= ['MKL','FB','AAPL','ADBE']

for ticker in tickers:
    page = requests.get('https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/'+ticker+'/company-people', headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    
    table = soup.find_all("table", {"class":"cr_dataTable cr_board_table"})[-1]
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [tr.text for tr in td]
        data.append(row)

print(data)
```

This code prints the list, "data," which is filled with two-part nested lists that look like this:

```
[['  Thomas Sinnickson Gayner  Co-Chief Executive Officer & Director ',
  ' Colfax Corp., Markel Corp., The Community Foundation, Inc., Cable One, Inc., Graham Holdings Co., WP Co. LLC, Diamond Healthcare Corp. '],
 ['  Richard Reeves Whitt  Co-Chief Executive Officer & Director ',
  ' Markel Corp., Virginia Foundation for Independent Colleges, World Affairs Council of Greater Richmond, Markel Capital Holdings Ltd., Alterra Capital America Ltd. '],
 ['  Anthony F. Markel  Vice Chairman ', ' Markel Corp. '],
 ['  Anne Lynne Puckett  Director ',
  ' Markel Corp., Simsmart Technologies, Inc., Howden Alphair Ventilating Systems, Inc., Howden Holdings Ltd., CAST Ltd., ESAB Group Russia Ltd., Victor Technologies Ltd., Victor Technologies (UK) Ltd., Exelvia Co., James Howden & Co. Ltd., Howden UK Ltd., Howden Compressors Ltd., Gas-Arc Group Ltd., H UK Engineering Ltd. ']]
```

**How do I append the variable (stock ticker) that was used originally to each nested list? Or, do I convert to df then add that way?**

The unfortunate part is that each variable in the stock ticker list pulls anywhere from 5-12 values, so it's not 1-1. Can't just apply to the ticker list as a new column in df because, for example, there may be 40 nested lists in the greater list but only 4 stock tickers.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks.

Comment: wheres the part of the code with the stock ticker variable?

Comment: and what I'd probably do is create a dictionary, and then you can append the data to it based on a key (in this case I'm thinking the tickers `MKL`,`FB`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Just had to append the ticker variable to the row before appending the row to the list, "data."

```
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [tr.text for tr in td]
        row.append(ticker)
        data.append(row)
```